# Why are certain JavaScript objects magical?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Try this, right here, from Safari or Chrome or what have you, in the inspector's JS console.

```
var x = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
> undefined

x.top;
> 0

x.top += 5;
> 5

x.top;
> 0
```

I had expected the object produced by `getBoundingClientRect()` to be a modifiable object. I have just shown this to be false. Neither does it stay in sync with the state of the browser, so if I scroll the page a bit, then check the value of `x.top`, it still reports `0` even though it should now be a negative value since I've scrolled down. At least, if I reassign x with another call to `getBoundingClientRect()` it would then report a negative value.

So, it doesn't respond to me trying to change it, but there doesn't appear to be some higher purpose to exhibiting that behavior.

Maybe there's some sort of clean way to explain this? Something better than **shrug* that's what it does.*

Comment: It (said object) just doesn't allow you to assign a new value. However the rectangle returned is *detached* from the DOM/window and the values are fixed as to what they were when it was obtained. So: 1) The object returned does not let properties be reassigned *and* 2; The object returned is *disconnected* from the view.

Comment: @user2864740 Right, so this is what I've discovered by stumbling into it, after scratching my head for the longest time wondering why my code (attempting to write to such an object, and having it silently fail to take assignments) wasn't working. I guess there isn't a way to avoid this sort of pitfall, not without the browser implementor changing how it works.

Comment: I think the only reliable way is to create a "pure" JS copy of the relevant object. There are a number of quirks (some prescribed and some not) by various different native-language interface implementations.

Comment: @user2864740 Agreed, that's clearly the way to reliably address the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect,

> ```
> rectObject = object.getBoundingClientRect();
> ```
>
> The returned value is a [TextRectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMClientRect) object which is the union of the
>   rectangles returned by [getClientRects()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getClientRects) for the element, i.e., the CSS
>   border-boxes associated with the element.

And according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMClientRect,

the attributes of the TextRectangle returned are **Read only**.

Moreover, the specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-clientrect-interface) says

```
interface ClientRect {
   readonly attribute float top;
   readonly attribute float right;
   readonly attribute float bottom;
   readonly attribute float left;
   readonly attribute float width;
   readonly attribute float height;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The `getBoundingClientRect` method does return a [`ClientRect` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-clientrect-interface) whose properties are specified to be read-only. *That's just how it works* :-) Most browsers will implement this as a property with a `writable: false` [descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor#Description) (but don't trust this, host objects may be implemented arbitrarily).

The higher purpose of this behaviour is that the method will return a *static snapshot* of the current values, which is detached from the *live* DOM and the changes made to it. The returned object is frozen therefore, and assigning to it does not make sense - there are other methods for changing the view.